# Finding rank of matrix from its characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

[image]

I have to find rank of the matrix from the given characteristic polynomial. 
Here is my attempt.

[image]

Now how to check other possibilities of rank ?

Comment: Do you know  the Jordan normal form of a matrix?

Comment: Jordan form is probably overkill here.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that the geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue is less than or equal to the algebraic multiplicity. In your case, since $\beta \neq 0$, the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$ is $3$ and the geometric multiplicity of $0$ is given by $\dim \ker A$ so we have $1 \leq \dim \ker A \leq 3$ (or equivalently, $2 \leq \operatorname{rank} A \leq 4$). By playing with examples of block diagonal matrices, you can see that indeed all three cases are possible.

Comment: You mean the geometric multiplicity of eigenvalue 0 is numerically equal to the nulity of matrix ?

Comment: @AbhishekChandra: Yep.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue $0$ is also the *kernel* (AKA nullspace) of $A$.  How does this relate to the rank?  What are the possible dimensions of this eigenspace?

Comment: I feel like this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @JEFFYELTON I respectfully disagree, pending feedback from the asker.

Comment: @JEFFYELTON I think this is the best answer possible (provided one doesn't do all the work for the OP).